# Sum of Conditional Probabilities of two discrete random values

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

While studying probability theory, I came across this truth statement. In my lecture notes, it has been depicted as False. However, according to my reasoning, it is supposed to be true.
Could someone share their opinions on this?

Truth Statement:

[image]

Comment: Suppose $X=Y$.  Then $P(X=x_i\,|\,Y=x_i)=1$ for all $i$.

Comment: For me the statement looks right. Were there any reasoning why the statement might be false.

Comment: Nope, unfortunately, there was no reasoning why the statement is false.

Comment: @beerjamin I cannot think of a counterexample for the statement.

Comment: Nothing rules out the possibility that $P(X=x_2)=0$.  In which case the stated formula fails for $i=2$.

Comment: Once again, Suppose $X=Y$ and the possible values for both are $(x_1,x_2)$.  Then $P(X=x_1\,|,Y=x_1)=1$ and $P(X=x_2\,|,Y=x_2)=1$ so the sum (in this case) is $2$, not $1$.

Comment: So what is your reasoning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This statement looks like a flawed version the law of total probability (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability). The first mistake is that the probability that $Y = y_{i}$ is missing. The second mistake is that the sum does not  equal 1, but it equals the probability of $X=x_{i}$, so
$ \mathbb{P}(X_{i}) = \sum\limits_{j=1}^{k} \mathbb{P}(X = x_{i} \mid Y = y_{j}) \mathbb{P}(Y = y_{i}), $ for all $i$.

Another possible way to correct the statement is as follows
$  \sum\limits_{i=1}^{m} \mathbb{P}(X_{i}) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{m} \sum\limits_{j=1}^{k} \mathbb{P}(X = x_{i} \mid Y = y_{j}) \mathbb{P}(Y = y_{i}) = 1,$
but then we lose the for all $i$ part of the equation.

A counterexample to the original statement is the following. Consider a deterministic random variable $X$, with $\mathbb{P}(X=0)=1$. Furthermore assume that $Y$ can take two values, 0 and 1, with probability 1/2 and that $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Then
$\mathbb{P}(X=0 \mid Y = 0) +  \mathbb{P}(X=0 \mid Y = 1) = 1 + 1 = 2$ (using the independence of $X$ and $Y$), but 
$\mathbb{P}(X=0 \mid Y = 0) \mathbb{P}(Y=0) +  \mathbb{P}(X=0 \mid Y = 1)\mathbb{P}(Y=1) = 1/2 + 1/2 = 1$.